Is it possible to bind a dictionary item into TextField?
In SwiftUI I'd like to store some key-value pair data in a dictionary. Can I bind an item in the dictionary to TextField or elsewhere that requires Binding?
I want to do something like this:
@State var myDic: [String : String] = [
    "name": "Tim"
    "company": "Apple"
]

TextField("Name", text: $myDic["name"] ?? "")

where the behavior is:

If the "name" exists in dictionary:

User editing in TextField will change the value.
User deleting the contents in TextField (setting it as ""), the dictionary removes the item of "name".


If the "name" not exists in dictionary:

The TextField display as empty ("").
User set value will let dictionary add that item and assign value.




I would create a custom Dictionary subscript.
extension Dictionary where Value == String {
    subscript(emptyStringAsNil key: Key) -> Value {
        get { self[key] ?? "" }
        set { self[key] = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : newValue }
    }
}

Usage:
TextField("Foo", text: $myDic[emptyStringAsNil: "name"])


After long-time trying, I have a solution for this problem. I think this can be separated into 2 requirements:

Nullable setter for dictionary (because the getter of dictionary is nullable).

extension Dictionary {
    
    subscript(removeNil key: Key) -> Value? {
        get { self[key] }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                self[key] = newValue
            } else {
                self.removeValue(forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }

}


Display nullable variable in TextField where requires non-nullable. As is required: 1) the default value is displayed, when it's nil; 2) it turns into nil when set to default value.

public extension Binding where Value: Equatable {
    static func ??(binding: Binding<Value?>, fallback: Value) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(
            get: { binding.wrappedValue ?? fallback },
            set: {
                if binding.wrappedValue == fallback {
                    binding.wrappedValue = nil
                } else {
                    binding.wrappedValue = $0
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

Then it can be used like this:
@State var myDic: [String: String] = [
    "a" : "a",
    "b" : "b",
]

TextField("foo", text: $myDic[removeNil: "a"] ?? "")
    .onChange(of: myDic) {
        print(myDic)
    }

Testing on macOS 14.4.1: When I type "a", and double "delete" to clear the TextField, the output is like shown below, exactly what is required.

